# Bind to List of objects that contain Dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I’ve got a Model class called BaseNode which has a Name property and a Dictionary property. I’ve got methods in this class to manage the Dictionary and there is a list of BaseNodes in my BaseNodeViewModel. In my example code below I have added 2 BaseNodes to the List, the first BaseNode has 3 entries in the Dictionary and the second one only 1. I want to bind this List to a ListView. However, I don’t just want to see the 2 BaseNodes in the list, I want to see 4: BaseNode.Name - “key value of dictionary from baseNode”.

What would be the best way to achieve this? I currently have a method: “UpdateBindBaseNodeList()” which fills up another List (BindBaseNodeList) with the name and key value of the Dictionary I then bind to this List instead. I don’t really like this solution because I’ll need to remember to update this list every time my original List changes.

Model:

```
...
public Dictionary<ushort, BitArray> MatIDBitArrayDictionary { get; set; }
...

public void CreateNewMaterialBitArray(ushort matID, int index, int size)
{
    var tempBitArray = new BitArray(size);
    tempBitArray.Set(index, true);

    MatIDBitArrayDictionary.Add(matID, tempBitArray);
}
```

Viewmodel:

```
{
    ...
    var testNode1 = new BaseNode();
    testNode1.Name = "TestNode";
    testNode1.CreateNewMaterialBitArray(0, 0, 100);
    testNode1.CreateNewMaterialBitArray(1, 10, 100);
    testNode1.CreateNewMaterialBitArray(2, 30, 100);

    var testNode2 = new BaseNode();
    testNode2.Name = "TestNode2";
    testNode2.CreateNewMaterialBitArray(10, 0, 100);

    BaseNodes.Add(testNode1);
    BaseNodes.Add(testNode2);

    UpdateBindBaseNodList();
}

private void UpdateBindBaseNodList()
{
    foreach (var baseNode in BaseNodes)
    {
        ushort[] usedMatIDs = baseNode.GetUsedMaterialIDsArray();
        foreach (ushort matID in usedMatIDs)
        {
            BindBaseNodeList.Add(baseNode.Name + " - " + matID);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors or incorrect results with the code you currently have?

Comment: No it's working, there are 5 elements in BindBaseNodeList after I call 'UpdateBindBaseNodeList()' and the ListView is binding / displaying them correctly. But that means another List I need to keep track of and update. I was hoping for a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It almost sounds like a hierarchical structure like a tree would be better suited to display this data. However, to answer your question, you want to "flatten" out the nested list nature of your data (hence the nested foreach loops you have) without manually creating a new list each time.

Without knowing any of the infrastructure you have in place, here is something that might work, albeit there are more elegant ways to do this.

First, add another property that will represent the flattened data you want to display in your ListView (kind of like you are doing in UpdateBindBaseNodList).

```
public IEnumerable<String> BaseNodeListFlattened
{
  get
  {
    foreach (var baseNode in BaseNodes)
    {
      foreach (ushort matId in baseNode.MatIDBitArrayDictionary.Keys)
      {
        yield return String.Format("{0} - {1}", baseNode.Name, matId);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This gets you the list anytime you ask for it. Now you just need a way to tell the View that it has been updated.

An `ObservableCollection` does nicely for our needs.
Given `ObservableCollection<BaseNode> BaseNodes;` ...
We can do this (perhaps in the constructor of your ViewModel) to tell the View anytime you change the list.

```
this.BaseNodes.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => this.OnPropertyChanged("BaseNodeListFlattened");
```

Now every time you add a node to your `BaseNodes` it will trigger the `CollectionChanged` event which will then call the `OnPropertyChanged` handler and inform the View to update the list, where it will read `BaseNodeListFlattened` and refresh its list of items.

And of course the corresponding xaml for the ListView...

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding BaseNodeListFlattened}"/>
```